# DJANGO - No module named 'estacion'

Tags: django, django-models

**Error:**

applications\dispositivo\models.py", line 2, in 
    from estacion.models import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'estacion'

Parece que dice que no encuentra la clase Estacion, pero sí que está. ¿Qué sucede?

**estacion/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Estacion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)

    class meta:
        verbose_name = 'Estación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Estaciones'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + '-' + self.name
```

**dispositivo/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from estacion.models import Estacion

# Create your models here.
class Dispositivo(models.Model):
    DEVICE_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        ('0','Datalogger'),
        ('1','radar'),
        ('2','modem'),
        ('3','radio')
    )
    #name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50,null=True)
    tipo_dispositivo = models.CharField('TipoDispositivo', max_length=1, choices=DEVICE_TYPE_CHOICE,null=True)
    marca = models.CharField('Marcha',max_length=50,null=True)
    modelo = models.CharField('Modelo',max_length=50,null=True)
    disp_numserie = models.CharField('NºSerie',max_length=100,null=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Estacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    class meta:
        verbose_name = 'Dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dispositivos'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.marca
```

Answer (score 0):

la ruta debe ser:

```
from **applications.estacion.models** import Estacion
```

y no:

```
from **estacion.models** import Estacion
```

(ya que la app está dentro de un directorio llamado applications)